# problems with "getElementsByClassName" in MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Tags: vba, web-scraping, vb6, microsoft.mshtml

The problem happens only when used getElementsByClassName

```
Dim HTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

HTTP.open "POST", strWWW, False
HTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0;     Windows NT 5.0)"
HTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
HTTP.send ("obj=" & strID)

Dim HTML As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

HTML.body.innerHTML = HTTP.responseText

Dim eleCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Set eleCol = HTML.getElementsByClassName("listEvent sro") '<-- The problem is happening here.
```

The tests are being done on Windows 8.1 and Windows XP

**Windows 8.1**

While in IDE everything works normally,
but when compiled simply the error appears:

[image: Error on Windows 8.1]

**mshtml.dll 11.00.9600.18860**

**mshtml.tlb 11.0.9600.16518**

The method exists, but now why it works while in IDE, but not when compiled?

**Windows XP**

Not even in the IDE worked, presenting
the following error message:

[image]

**mshtml.dll 8.0.6001.23588**

**mshtml.tlb 8.0.6001.18702 (old version and there is no getElementsByClassName)**

**mshtml.tlb 11.0.9600.16518 (using this version but it does not work)**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following workaround which uses css selector syntax to select by class. With modern browsers it is a faster method for matching on elements. It may work.

```
Dim eleCol As Object
Set eleCol = HTML.querySelectorAll(".listEvent.sro")
```

Also, test whether you can remove the compound class usage and have a single class e.g.

```
Set eleCol = HTML.querySelectorAll(".listEvent")
```

You use a `For Loop` from `0` to `.Length -1` over the returned `nodeList`.

Answer (score 0):

**Your tip solved the problem.**

The list of nodes I used...

```
Dim eleMen As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

For Each eleMen In eleCol
    debug.print eleMen.innerText
Next eleMen
```

... and it worked perfectly, the same way when not used
`HTML.getElementsByClassName`
How much do I use `getElementsByTagName` also works normally, only
`getElementsByClassName` that is displaying this error in the executable,
and not in the IDE.

Is it a bug in MSHTML?

Another detail is that this worked without problems too ...

```
Set eleCol = HTML.querySelectorAll(".listEvent.sro").Item(0).getElementsByTagName("td")
```

... returned all the nodes I need.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you getting an exception? What error is it displaying?